# Error Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force while installing homebrew on mac

Tags: macos, homebrew

While installing homebrew on my mac Os version - 10.14.5

I am getting the below error:-

```
in-iftekhar-04eb:~ iftekhar.khan$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 203980ac5 Merge pull request #6309 from Homebrew/dependabot/bundler/docs/html-pipeline-2.11.1
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:254:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /private/tmp (Errno::EACCES)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:254:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `reverse_each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `mkdir_p'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/pathname.rb:576:in `mkpath'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/config.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:27:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force
```

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
sudo install -d -o $(whoami) -g admin /private
```

or perhaps:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

↳ https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/7732946

Comment: Tried this and it worked:

    `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

thank you.